# VBA script macro save to specific location

Tags: file-location

How do alter the following script so that it saves to a specific folder instead of asking?

```
Sub Saveaspdfandsend()
Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range

Set xSht = ActiveSheet
Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
   xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
Else
   MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
   Exit Sub
End If
xFolder = xFolder + "\" + xSht.Name + Format(Now, " yyyy-mm-dd hmmAM/PM") + ".pdf"

'Check if file already exist
If Len(Dir(xFolder)) > 0 Then
    xYesorNo = MsgBox(xFolder & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", _
                      vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
    On Error Resume Next
    If xYesorNo = vbYes Then
        Kill xFolder
    Else
        MsgBox "if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make sure the file is not open or write protected." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
    'Save as PDF file
    xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xFolder, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

    'Create Outlook email
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
    With xEmailObj
        .Display
        .To = ""
        .CC = "csc.canada@philips.com"
        .Subject = xSht.Name + ".pdf"
        .Attachments.Add xFolder
        If DisplayEmail = False Then
            '.Send
        End If
    End With
Else
  MsgBox "The active worksheet cannot be blank"
  Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

With Thanks, 
Michael

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Where did you get this script and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that the selected item is being put in to a variable called *xFolder*. Comment out the section about xFileDlg down to where xFolder is appended to.

Change that to whatever you want:

```
xFolder = xFolder + "\" + xSht.Name + Format(Now, " yyyy-mm-dd hmmAM/PM") + ".pdf"
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark the solution. Green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you are having to pick a folder is this part..

> Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
>
> If xFileDlg.Show = True Then    xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
>   Else    MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." &
>   vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must
>   Specify Destination Folder"    Exit Sub End If

This is great if you want to pick the folder every time or you need to create a new folder.  But if the folder exist and you are always going to save it to the same place then just take out the above part and just manually add the folder location.

Example:
xFolder = "C:\MyPDFs" + "\" + xSht.Name + Format(Now, " yyyy-mm-dd hmmAM/PM") + ".pdf"